# URL Navigation with HyperLinkField inside a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I'm using a `HyperLinkField` inside a `gridview`, and I want to link to another *URL + an ID.*

```
<div id="searchResults" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvSearchResult" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" 
    CaptionAlign="NotSet" CellPadding="5">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Användare">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("UName")%>
                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="UName" 
                            DataNavigateUrlFormatString='/MemberPages/profile.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("PID") %>'
                            DataTextField="UName" 
                            HeaderText="Besök sida" 
                            SortExpression="Name" 
                            ItemStyle-Width="100px"
                            ItemStyle-Wrap="true" />
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

The `gridview` is using `datasource` and `databind`. It's complaining about:

```
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="/MemberPages/profile.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("PID") %>"
```

I'm not sure where to use `<%# Eval("PID") %>`, I'm sure there is something like PID, I've doublechecked.

If I'm using `NavigateUrl="/MemberPages/profile.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("PID") %>"` I also get the same error:

```
Literal content ('<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="UName" 
                               DataNavigateUrlFormatString="/MemberPages/profile.aspx?ID=') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection'.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need to use " inside attribute value, use ' as delimiter

```
Attribute='Some value with " symbol'
```

If you need to use ' inside attribute value, use "

```
Attribute="Some value with ' symbol"
```

Also change your column definition

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="PID" 
                    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="/MemberPages/profile.aspx?ID={0}"
                    DataTextField="UName" 
                    HeaderText="Besök sida" 
                    SortExpression="Name" 
                    ItemStyle-Width="100px"
                    ItemStyle-Wrap="true" />
```

In DataNavigateUrlFormatString attribute you use data column specified in DataNavigateUrlFields (the formating is similar to String.Format method).

Comment: the data-binding tag gav me:  Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkField does not have a DataBinding event.

Comment: Thank you so much! You made my day. Been studying for 12hours today and finally can I go to bed :) Thanks!

Comment: but, can you please tell me what {0} is doing?

Comment: You will find description [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)

Comment: I have to open different pages on different rows of gridview as related to the contents in the specific cell of the row. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is replace the below line

DataNavigateUrlFormatString="/MemberPages/profile.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("PID") %>"

with the line below

DataNavigateUrlFormatString='/MemberPages/profile.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("PID") %>'

notice I replaced the double quotes with single quotes and the beginning and end.

Comment: wops. Saw that now. Changed it (and edited the question) but i still don't get the correct URL. '/MemberPages/profile.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("PID") %>' should be '/MemberPages/profile.aspx?ID=10'

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer does work. For my case I needed to use a different control. This example lets you use the Eval with the URL string.

```
<asp:LinkButton PostBackUrl='<%#"~/config.aspx?Id=" + Eval("Id") %>'  runat="server">Configuration</asp:LinkButton>
```